How to get the correct screen pixel from a coordinate with OpenLayers?
This should be an easy one, but I am not sure where the information I need is found.
When clicking on the white dot as the app is run,

it will log a coordinate like [750,216.66666666666666].
Now, move the white dot to the left until it wraps around and appears on the right.

it will log a coordinate like [-59.16853932584246,178.55640684382806].
The X coordinate is wrong.
If the white dot was instead moved to the right to approximately the same spot,

clicking on it will log a coordinate like [1449.9848745225447,166.78267751332552], which is what I need.
I need to know how to get the translation factor so I can apply it to the X coordinate and get the correct number.
How can I obtain that translation factor?
This factor cannot come from the click event. I need to be able to use information from the map itself.
If, for example, I move the white dot to the left until it wraps around and appears on the right and then I zoom in on the dot and click, it will log a coordinate like [-9708.575728449725, 88.81498717307477]. That is a large negative X coordinate.
What space is that coordinate in? i.e. what space does getPixelFromCoordinate return a coordinate in? Is it a pixel on the canvas? Is it possible to simply get a canvas offset to convert it to the absolute div coordinate (what event.pixel would contain)?
Again, I cannot use event.pixel to get the coordinate as I need the coord outside of event handling. I need to start with a coordinate.


const osm = new ol.source.OSM();

osm.setTileGridForProjection(
  "EPSG:4326",
  ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({ extent: [-180, -90, 180, 90] })
);

const tileLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({ source: osm });
const coordinate = [-97, 38];

const point = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(coordinate),
  properties: {}
});

const layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [point]
  }),

  style: (feature) => {
    const properties = feature.getProperties();
    let style;

    style = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 10,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: "#FFF" }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: "#FFF",
          width: 2
        })
      })
    });

    return style;
  }
});

const map = new ol.Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [tileLayer, layer],
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: "EPSG:4326",
    center: coordinate,
    zoom: 2
  }),
  controls: ol.control.defaults.defaults({ attribution: false, zoom: false })
});

map.on("click", (event) => {
  if (event.dragging) {
    return;
  }

  const pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(coordinate);
  console.log(pixel);
});

ol.proj.get("EPSG:4326").setExtent([-180, -85, 180, 85]);
#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 1500px;
}
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/10.2.1/ol.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/10.2.1/dist/ol.min.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>




Calculate which wrapped world you are clicking on, then adjust the feature coordinate by that number of world widths.


const osm = new ol.source.OSM();

osm.setTileGridForProjection(
  "EPSG:4326",
  ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({ extent: [-180, -90, 180, 90] })
);

const tileLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({ source: osm });
const coordinate = [-97, 38];

const point = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(coordinate),
  properties: {}
});

const layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [point]
  }),

  style: (feature) => {
    const properties = feature.getProperties();
    let style;

    style = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 10,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: "#FFF" }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: "#FFF",
          width: 2
        })
      })
    });

    return style;
  }
});

const map = new ol.Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [tileLayer, layer],
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: "EPSG:4326",
    center: coordinate,
    zoom: 2
  }),
  controls: ol.control.defaults.defaults({ attribution: false, zoom: false })
});

map.on("click", (event) => {
  if (event.dragging) {
    return;
  }

  const world = Math.floor((event.coordinate[0] + 180) / 360);
  const pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(
    [coordinate[0] + 360 * world, coordinate[1]]
  );
  console.log(pixel);
});

ol.proj.get("EPSG:4326").setExtent([-180, -85, 180, 85]);
#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 1500px;
}
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/10.2.1/ol.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/10.2.1/dist/ol.min.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>



Or use the view center to calculate the world:


const osm = new ol.source.OSM();

osm.setTileGridForProjection(
  "EPSG:4326",
  ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({ extent: [-180, -90, 180, 90] })
);

const tileLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({ source: osm });
const coordinate = [-97, 38];

const point = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(coordinate),
  properties: {}
});

const layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [point]
  }),

  style: (feature) => {
    const properties = feature.getProperties();
    let style;

    style = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 10,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: "#FFF" }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: "#FFF",
          width: 2
        })
      })
    });

    return style;
  }
});

const map = new ol.Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [tileLayer, layer],
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: "EPSG:4326",
    center: coordinate,
    zoom: 2
  }),
  controls: ol.control.defaults.defaults({ attribution: false, zoom: false })
});

map.on("click", (event) => {
  if (event.dragging) {
    return;
  }

  const center = map.getView().getCenter();
  let world = Math.floor((center[0] + 180) / 360);
  const normalizedLon = center[0] - 360 * world;
  if (normalizedLon - coordinate[0] < -180) {
    world--;
  } else if (normalizedLon - coordinate[0] > 180) {
    world++;
  }
  const pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(
    [coordinate[0] + 360 * world, coordinate[1]]
  );
  console.log(pixel);
});

ol.proj.get("EPSG:4326").setExtent([-180, -85, 180, 85]);
#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 1500px;
}
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/10.2.1/ol.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/10.2.1/dist/ol.min.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>




Thank you for this answer. How can I calculate the wrapped world from information in map and not the event? In my real case, I will not have the event information. I have updated my question.

You could use map.getView().getCenter()

I am not sure how that helps. Could you update your answer using map.getView().getCenter()?

I have added another example

Unfortunately, using the center is not working. If I shift the white dot to the left until it appears on the right, the computed X coordinate is negative. The first example isn't working either.

If, for example, I move the white dot to the left until it wraps around and appears on the right and then I zoom in on the dot and click, it will log a coordinate like [-9708.575728449725, 88.81498717307477]. That is a large negative X coordinate. What space is that coordinate in? i.e. what space does getPixelFromCoordinate return a coordinate in? Is it a pixel on the canvas? Is it possible to simply get a canvas offset to convert it to the absolute div coordinate (what event.pixel would contain)? But, I cannot use event.pixel to get the coord as I need the coord outside of event handling.

It also needs to adjust the calculated world if the difference between the center and feature is greater than 180 degrees, I have updated  the last example to reflect that.

Your script has an error in it. world is const, but then it is reassigned with world++, for example. Also, I believe your world++ and world-- need to be swapped. After I swapped them, I believe I can confirm this works.

You are right.  I am surprised it did not throw an error when run as a snippet.  Updated now.

Brilliant. You are a rock star. Thank you. I think something like this may make a good utility function to add as a sibling of getPixelFromCoordinate.
